# PHP access external $var from within a class function

Tags: php, global-variables

In PHP, how do you use an external $var for use within a function in a class? For example, say $some_external_var sets to true and you have something like

```
class myclass {
bla ....
bla ....

function myfunction()  {

  if (isset($some_external_var)) do something ...

   } 

}


$some_external_var =true;

$obj = new myclass();
$obj->myfunction();
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks everybody, its not a class dependent $var and its seldom used in just one area. Basically, this var is used to include another file for the function output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Global $some_external_var;`

```
function myfunction()  {
  Global $some_external_var;
  if (!empty($some_external_var)) do something ...

   } 

}
```

But because Global automatically sets it, check if it isn't empty.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword inside your function, to make your external variable visible to that function.

For instance :

```
$my_var_2 = 'glop';

function test_2()
{
    global $my_var_2;
    var_dump($my_var_2);  // string 'glop' (length=4)
}

test_2();
```

You could also use the `$GLOBALS` array, which is always visible, even inside functions.

But it is generally not considered a good practice to use global variables: your classes should not depend on some kind of external stuff that might or might not be there !

A better way would be to pass the variables you need as parameters, either to the methods themselves, or to the constructor of the class...

Answer (score 3):

that's bad software design. In order for a class to function, it needs to be provided with data. So, pass that external var into your class, otherwise you're creating unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just pass this variable during __construct() and make what the object does during construction conditional on the truth value of that variable?

Comment: In newer versions of PHP you don't even need __construct() - you can create a function with the name of the class and it behaves as the constructor.

For example, say you have a class called TestClass

    class TestClass
    {
        private x;
        function TestClass(y)
        {
            this->x = y;
        }
    }

This would be a valid constructor.

But I agree...I would pass it into the constructor.

Comment: Joe Morgan, I'm pretty sure it was that older versions didn't support the __construct magic method, and **required** the constructor to share the class's name.

Comment: Argh, stupid broken half-Markdown. That was the `__construct` magic method.

Comment: And I knew the name of his class how?

Answer (score 0):

Use Setters and Getters or maybe a centralized config like:

```
function config()
{
  static $data;

  if(!isset($data))
  {
    $data = new stdClass();
  }

  return $data;
}

class myClass
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        echo "config()->myConfigVar: " . config()->myConfigVar;
    }
}
```

and the use it:

```
config()->myConfigVar = "Hello world";

$myClass = new myClass();
$myClass->myFunction();
```

http://www.evanbot.com/article/universally-accessible-data-php/24